# Internal Server Error when returning list of custom objects using Response object

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am working on jersey Restful webservices and using Advanced rest client (for Chrome) to test the results. I am facing the following issue.

Following code return me an error stating Error 500 :Internal Server Error

```
@Path("/test")

public class TestWebService
{

@Context private HttpServletRequest req;

@GET
@Path("check")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response TestMethod()
{
     Response resp = null;
     //some code here
     ......

     List<Foobar> foolist = getResult();
     //Here Foobar is some custom class and get result returns a list of objects of Foobar

      resp = Response.ok(foolist).build();
      return resp;
    }
}
```

while if i do a small change in return type, where i return `List<Foobar>` instead of `Response object`, it works totally fine.

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestWebService
{

  @Context private HttpServletRequest req;

  @GET
  @Path("check")
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public List<Foobar> TestMethod()
  {
    //some code here
    ......

    List<Foobar> foolist = getResult();
    //Here Foobar is some custom class, and getResult returns a list of objects of Foobar

    return foolist;
  }
}
```

Am i going wrong somewhere? I have tried returning single object instead of list of objects through `Response` object. It works perfectly fine. But i don't know what is the issue if i return a `List`.

Comment: Try returning an Object that has the list as a member ;)

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. This should be easy to do on Java EE 7. Can `Foobar` be serialzed to JSON and/or XML? Do you use JAXB annotations on it?

Comment: @Fildor: Well that would be my last option i think :)

Comment: @LutzHorn: I am not exactly sure about serialization. I used JAXB annotations properly. i kind of think this might be related to serialization but i didn't find anything relevant yet.

Comment: Do you get exceptions? They may be swallowed ...

Comment: I did not write client code. I am using Advanced Rest client for chrome browser for testing. Server code never throws any exception, but it shows 500 error code in client application. I think i need to write client code for getting detailed error and to find exact exception.

Comment: Hm, I suspect the server to swallow an exception by catching it and delivering the 500 - error. Maybe make a debug-version of your app with a big try-catch in that function and see if one gets caught. Then you can work your way through its stacktrace.

Comment: Something is throwing an exception and your container is mapping that to a 500 response. Check your server logs or follow @Fildor's suggestion. If you're curious, the exception-handling behavior is described in the jax-rs and servlet specifications.

Comment: Can you specify the version of Jersey and the container you're using?